# A region in the plane that has to intersect unit circle

Tags: geometry, analysis

If a region (meaning open, connected and non-empty subset) of the plane intersects the unit circle, does it mean it has to contain points both inside and outside of the unit circle?

I wanted to make sure that there is no weird construction that would provide a counter-example to containing points from both inside and outside?

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: First prove this in the case when your region is an open round disk.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it would have to contain a point both inside and outside the circle.

Let $P$ be a point of the circle and $U_\epsilon$ an epsilon neighborhood of $P$ centered at $P$ and contained in the region.

Then the ray from the origin containing $P$ contains points of the region at distances $1-\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $1+\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ from the origin.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sketch of a proof. I imagine you will be able to fill in the gaps.

Suppose that $U$ is a region you describe which intersects a point $p$ on the unit circle. Suppose without loss of generality that $p = 1 $. Since $U$ is open there is some disk  contained in $U$ centred at $1$. This disk must contain points in the interval $(-1,1)$.

Comment: Also it is probably valuable to consider which properties of $U$ are actually used in this proof

Comment: Nice!! Thank you. Yeah I think I can fill in details with justification.